# How to release different versions of the Android app on different testing tracks on Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have an Android app currently live on Play Store with version 1.0.0. Today I released 1.0.1 on Beta track to Testers T1 & T2. But I have another version 1.0.2 but I want to release it to only Testers T3 & T4. How can I do this? Do I need to release it on a separate testing track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to release it on a separate testing track